# What is the difference between @Deprecated vs @Deprecated()?

Tags: java, annotations, java-annotations

Came across this `@Deprecated()` today. Curious to know `@Deprecated` vs `@Deprecated()` but both are resolving to the same interface `Deprecated` by the compiler.

Are they both different or are they same? Is there some practice to use one over another?

Comment: If they both return to the same interface, why do you think they might be different?

Comment: This is basic syntax of annotations (which this is) which can take parameters. The syntax for no parameters is no brackets or empty brackets, which are identical in effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both mean the same thing. `@Deprecated` is simply shorthand for `@Deprecated()`. See [§9.7.2. Marker Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-9.html#jls-MarkerAnnotation) of the *Java Language Specification*:

> A *marker annotation* is a shorthand designed for use with marker annotation types (§9.6.1).
>
> ```
> MarkerAnnotation:
> @ TypeName
> ```
>
> It is shorthand for the normal annotation:
>
> > ```
> > @TypeName()
> > ```
>
> It is legal to use marker annotations for annotation types with elements, so long as all the elements have default values (§9.6.2).
>
> > #### Example 9.7.2-1. Marker Annotations
> >
> > <sup>*Here is an example using the `Preliminary` marker annotation type from §9.6.1:*</sup>
> >
> > ```
> > @Preliminary public class TimeTravel { ... }
> > ```

As of Java 8 the `@Deprecated` annotation had no elements, so it could only ever be a marker annotation. Since Java 9, however, it now has two elements: `since` and `forRemoval`. But since those elements have default values the annotation can still be used as a marker annotation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an interface, it is an [annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/). `@Deprecated` and `@Deprecated()` are the same